# Ruby - how to read registry keys for 32 bit and 64 bit applications from 32 bit ruby

Tags: ruby, windows, ruby-on-rails-3, registry, win32ole

I am using ruby 32 bit in my application. I am using "win32/registry" for reading registry keys.

When i use

```
reg = Win32::Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.open('SOFTWARE\app_path')
reg_typ, reg_val = reg.read('somekey')
```

It by default reads in path

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\app_path

.

Now some of the applications are 64 bit and I want to check for

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\app_path

h. But, by default it always try to find under "WOW6432Node"

Any suggestion on what I am missing and how can i read registry for both 32 and 64 bit applications from ruby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently `win32/registry` is not defining the [`KEY_WOW64_{32,64}KEY` flags](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384129(v=vs.85).aspx) which are used to do that. But since Ruby allows re-opening classes and modules you can easily add them on your own:

```
module Win32::Registry::Constants
  KEY_WOW64_64KEY = 0x0100
  KEY_WOW64_32KEY = 0x0200
end
```

To read a 64-bit key:

```
reg = Win32::Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.open('SOFTWARE\app_path',
        Win32::Registry::KEY_READ | Win32::Registry::KEY_WOW64_64KEY)
```

To read a 32-bit key:

```
reg = Win32::Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.open('SOFTWARE\app_path',
        Win32::Registry::KEY_READ | Win32::Registry::KEY_WOW64_32KEY)
```

You can open a feature request for that on [Ruby's bug tracker](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/) (or I can do it for you if you prefer).

Comment: This works. thanks for the suggestion. Open the feature request https://github.com/ruby/bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/89